# NodeJS non-blocking I/O nature

Tags: node.js, express, postman, node-request

I read about non-blocking nature of nodeJS, and how I/O operations are non-blocking. I created a simple test to prove this

```
var request = require('request');
var http = require('http');
var express = require('express');

var app = express();

app.get('/test1', function (req, res) {
  res.sendStatus(httpStatus.OK);
});
app.get('/test2', function (req, res) {
  request.get('https://httpbin.org/delay/15', function () {
    res.sendStatus(httpStatus.OK);
  });
});
var server = http.createServer(app);
server.listen(3003);

module.exports = app;
```

That's the whole test. `test1` endpoint returns OK immediately, while `test2` returns OK after 15 seconds due to http request that is sent. When I call `test2` and immediately after that call `test1`, the response for `test1` is returned after 15 seconds. I would expect if I/O operations are non-blocking that response for `test1` is going to be returned immediately.

What am I missing?

**UPDATE:**

I was sending requests using Postman with **Interceptor** turned on. In that case Postman can send only *one request to a single host at a time*.

So nodeJS non-blocking I/O works perfectly fine, the issue was related to Postman Interceptor plugin.

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your question. Is the code you've shown the code you have questions about? Or did you make changes?

Comment: @4castle yes that's the code, the test2 endpoint makes call to service which returns response after 15 seconds

Comment: I try your code and it works fine! how you send request to your routes ?

Comment: @David I send them using postman

Comment: The `test1` response should be immediate according to that code. Are you sure you didn't reverse them?

Comment: ok I tried in Chrome now, it works fine, so it's Postman related issue
Thanks for your help

Comment: try to use ```curl -XGET http://localhost:3003/test1``` from your console it work for me

Comment: @David yes, curl also works, so it's Postman specific problem. It seems that it can send only one request to single sever at a time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those operations are non-blocking and this is demonstrated by your code example - I only fixed it in one place because it wasn't working with `httpStatus` being undefined - maybe that was your problem. See:

```
var request = require('request');
var http = require('http');
var express = require('express');

var app = express();

app.get('/test1', function (req, res) {
  res.sendStatus(200);
});
app.get('/test2', function (req, res) {
  request.get('https://httpbin.org/delay/15', function () {
    res.sendStatus(200);
  });
});
var server = http.createServer(app);
server.listen(3003);

module.exports = app;
```

And run it:

```
time curl http://localhost:3003/test1
OK
real    0m0.015s
user    0m0.007s
sys 0m0.004s
```

and:

```
time curl http://localhost:3003/test2
OK
real    0m10.466s
user    0m0.000s
sys 0m0.014s
```

In fact you can even see that you can request the long running endpoint multiple times concurrently, and all responses will be printed at the same time:

```
curl http://localhost:3003/test2 &
curl http://localhost:3003/test2 &
curl http://localhost:3003/test2 &
OKOKOK
```

which proves that not only the `/test1` endpoint is not blocking but also that the `/test2` endpoint is not blocking either.

Comment: See the update I added, the issue was related to Postman which I used to send the requests